# Restricting DBpedia Lookup Service API to search only in labels

Tags: lookup, dbpedia

[DBpedia Page](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/lookup/) states that when keyword search is performed, it searches for label as well as the anchor text (text used to refer the target entity). Hence, when searched for an entity 'Aaron', the first result returned is for the entity 'Elvis Presley', because the entity is referred by the anchor text 'Aaron'.

Is there some way to restrict this search to label only? A way around is to get around 10-20 results and then check ourselves for the label field.

Comment: Are you writing a SPARQL query? How are you searching? If you are using SPARQL, it is easy to just look up labels.

Comment: No, not SPARQL, but by API call by URL like `http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryClass=person&MaxHits=1&QueryString=Adam%20Sandler`